# Managedbass MP3 Play

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, bass

I managed to play different .wav sources play on different output via Managedbass but I can only play them in wav format.
Solo mp3 play is working(when I just send the .mp3 to soundcard) but when I try to point them to different outs, no luck.

```
string file1 = @"F:\test1.wav";
string file2 = @"F:\test2.wav";
string file3 = @"F:\test3.wav";
string file4 = @"F:\test4.wav";
```

```
Bass.Init(-1, 44100, DeviceInitFlags.Default, IntPtr.Zero); 
streamFL = Bass.CreateStream(file1, 0L, 0L, BassFlags.SpeakerFrontLeft); 
streamFR = Bass.CreateStream(file2, 0L, 0L, BassFlags.SpeakerFrontRight); 
streamSL = Bass.CreateStream(file3, 0L, 0L, BassFlags.SpeakerRearCenterLeft); 
streamSR = Bass.CreateStream(file4, 0L, 0L, BassFlags.SpeakerRearCenterRight);
```

After that, for playing.

```
Bass.ChannelPlay(streamFL, false);
Bass.ChannelPlay(streamFR, false);
Bass.ChannelPlay(streamCL, false);
Bass.ChannelPlay(streamCR, false);
```

It works like this for .wav files but when I changed files to .mp3 it doesn't works. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, are you getting an error or is it just playing the MP3 on all speakers?

Comment: No error, it just sends mp3 to front L and R. I am not able to send tracks to different outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
streamFL = Bass.CreateStream(file1, 0, 0, BassFlags.Mono | BassFlags.SpeakerFrontLeft | BassFlags.);
```

added mono flags for the command.